# Angular : insert ag-Grid in Prime-ng tabPanel

Tags: angular, primeng, ag-grid

I'm trying to insert a grid of data from `ag-grid` inside a `tabPanel` of a `Prime-ng tabView` component :

```
<p-tabView>
  <p-tabPanel [header]="'Tab I'" leftIcon="fa-print">
    <div class="ui-g-12">
      <ag-grid-angular style="width: 500px; height: 115px;" class="ag-fresh"
                       [rowData]="rowData"
                       [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
      </ag-grid-angular>
    </div>
  </p-tabPanel>
  <p-tabPanel [header]="'Tab II'" leftIcon="fa-print">
    <div class="ui-g-12">
      <ag-grid-angular style="width: 500px; height: 115px;" class="ag-fresh"
                       [rowData]="rowData"
                       [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
      </ag-grid-angular>
    </div>
    This text insert correctly the previous grid inside the tabPanel...
  </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
```

The problem is in my `Tab I` the grid is displayed outside the `tabPanel container` of the `Tab I` but if I add other elements after the grid (e.g text), all elements are correctly displayed inside the `tabPanel` container. It is the case for `Tab II`

I already tried to replace `ag-grid` with `Prime-ng dataList` component and I didn't encouter this problem. However I really need to use `ag-grid`.

My solution is to add, after the grid, a text with the same color as the backgroung color but it is not a satisfying solution.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having a similar problem where ag-grid looses all css formatting when placed inside an app using the PrimeNg library.

Comment: UPDATE: My solution was adding the following to the angular-cli app's styles.css:
`@import '../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
@import '../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/theme-fresh.css';`

Comment: I alreday have these lines in my angular-cli. I add `<hr style="visibility: hidden">` at the end of each tab.